# Django `assertNumQueries` showing duplicate queries on deferred field

Tags: python, django

I am having a strange behaviour that I cannot find out why it's happening.
I have a simple queryset with a deferred field, for example `Person.objects.filter(id=4).defer('phone')` and then I have a test that asserts this:

```py
with self.assertNumQueries(2):
   p = Person.objects.filter(id=4).defer('phone').first() # 1 query
   p.phone # 1 query
```

It fails, because it seems to run three queries on that block: the first one when filtering, and two more duplicate queries that come from the `p.phone` statement (SELECT phone FROM ...).

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

- Note: i'm using Django 2.0. And it also happens using `only()`, the counterpart of `defer()`.

Comment: What does the duplicated query look like?

Comment: @Ben it's the expected SELECT phone FROM ... The problem is that it's being executed twice. ```SELECT `person`.`id`,`person`.`phone`, FROM `person` WHERE (`person`.`id` = 4)```. At least that's what assertNumQueries is showing.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce, it's something related to your case. I wrote this test case with default Django user that passes. Provide more info if you need a better answer.

```
class TestDefer(APITestCase):
    def test_defer(self):
        u = User.objects.create(email='aaa@bbb.com', is_staff=True)
        with self.assertNumQueries(1):
            p = User.objects.defer('is_staff').get(id=u.id)
        with self.assertNumQueries(1):
            print(p.is_staff)

        with self.assertNumQueries(1):
            p = User.objects.defer('email').get(id=u.id)
        with self.assertNumQueries(1):
            print(p.email)
```